# Object Oriented Web Programming

Tags: web-development

OOP does not seem to be very popular these days. But before talking about "programming paradigms", we should talk about the tasks we have to solve. I strongly belive, there are different tasks to solve, that need different tools. But even if I´m wrong, why not use different tools, even if maybe one is a bit better than another?

I love the concepts of OOP, not because they are so nice, but because I had many good experiences in the past. Some very complex applications had to be maintained years later, and in most cases, this was easy to do.

When I started with web programming, I was strongly missing the comfort and ease I was used to. It was a bit like going 20 years back in the past and using tools and concepts, I thougt I newer would be forced to use: Why should I do work that a computer can do better? Why deal with strange AJAX calls, that are asynchronous and slow, if the computer can hide the details from me? Node-RED ist a tool of this kind, that hides all the details from the user, but allows to concentrate on the important things.

So, now I´m looking for tools or projects, that share this attitude: Supply a smart and universal programming tool for web applications, that hides most of the technical detail from the user, without being too specific. Not a webside-buldider, that can generate websites only, more a general tool that can be used for ANY task: Writing a calculation tool or a video game.

So, are there any recommendations for this kind of tools? I was very happy with Visual Studio or the Delphi IDE, so maybe this could be a template for what I´m looking for.

Comment: Hiding the details from the **user**, the end-user that's it, is very good. Hiding the details from the **developer** is not so good. As the programmer, you must know certain details to build and debug your website, and those that you hide will only bite you later on.

Comment: Besides, the question is just too broad. Pretty much any tool capable of developing websites will do what you want. Do you want an IDE? A programming language? With what features? To solve which problems?

Comment: Who says OOP does not seem to be very popular these days? There is no modern Programming language which is not OO. Which Programming language you using for Web Programming? Only with information about your perefered programming languge, you´ll get a suitable solution.

Comment: I know, the question is broad, but I think the question is clear: Could you recommend a smart and universal programming tool/language for web applications? If someone asked this to me for windows applications, I would recommend Object-Pascal/Delphi, as is a well organizes language, has a great IDE and good community support.

For the Web, I´m still looking for a similar performance. Currently I´m going with vanulla JS and VSCode, but that is far from being perfect. Currently checking out dart/flutter, which is nice, but has a small community. But maybe there are other recommendations.